# Не получается сделать ajax запрос на node js сервер

Tags: ajax, node.js

Мне выдается ошибка:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Я на php обходил её добавляя в headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, но сделав тут `response.writeHead(200, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` ошибка не ушла.

Comment: Попробуйте `response.writeHead(200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":  "*"});`

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой и помогло следующее решение:

Правки **на сервере node.js**

1) добавляем библиотеку cors

```
const cors = require('cors'); // предварительно сделать npm install cors или yarn add cors
```

2) Если вы используете express

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Мне помогло, надеюсь Вам тоже поможет!

Comment: К сожалению cors не спас. В комментариях Darth написал response.writeHead(200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}); это помогло.

Comment: Отлично! Главное, что вопрос решен :)

Comment: Это да, спасибо за помощь!